# Custom Font for an Android App

Tags: java, android, fonts

I tried to add a custom font in my app. The method creating a `typeface` object and putting a font in it worked. Now I want to make a class for the custom font for having a cleaner code.

**CustomFont.java**

```
public class CustomFont extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Slabo.ttf");

    public CustomFont(TextView textView) {
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

and now I am trying to add this font to a `textview`:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Typeface typeface;
    private CustomFont customFont;
    private TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/Slabo.ttf"); // works
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewTest);
        //textview.setTypeface(typeface); // works

        customFont = new CustomFont(textview);   // does not work

    }
}
```

but if I run this project I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all `CustomFont` should not be activity.It should be normal class.

```
public class CustomFont {

    private Typeface typeface;
    public CustomFont(Context context) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Slabo.ttf");
    }
    public void setFont(TextView textView) {
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

And call it from your MainActivity

```
customFont = new CustomFont(this);
customFont.setFont(textview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
text.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make method like below in your commonUtill class for better clarification

```
 public static void setTypeface(Context mContext, View view, VIEW_TYPE type,
                                   TYPE_FACE face, int bold) {
        View mView = view;
        Typeface tface = getTypeface(mContext, face);
        switch (type) {
            case TEXTVIEW:
                ((TextView) mView).setTypeface(tface, bold);
                break;
            case BUTTON:
                ((Button) mView).setTypeface(tface, bold);
                break;
            case EDITTEXT:
                ((EditText) mView).setTypeface(tface, bold);
                break;
            case RADIOBUTTON:
                ((RadioButton) mView).setTypeface(tface, bold);
                break;
            case CHECKBOX:
                ((CheckBox) mView).setTypeface(tface, bold);
                break;
            case CHECKEDTEXTVIEW:
                ((CheckedTextView) mView).setTypeface(tface, bold);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

and create function like this

```
public static enum TYPE_FACE {
        CALIBRI, ICON_FONT, BEBAS, AWESOME, BT, TAGLINE,
         CALLIBRI, WEBLYSLEEK, WEBLYSLEEK_BOLD, ICON_FONT1

    }
```

and your view method.

```
public static enum VIEW_TYPE {
        TEXTVIEW, BUTTON, EDITTEXT, RADIOBUTTON, CHECKBOX, CHECKEDTEXTVIEW
    }
```

by this way you can easily manage your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create `Java` class like this..

```
public class TextViewKarlaBold extends TextView {
    public TextViewKarlaBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TextViewKarlaBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TextViewKarlaBold(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/Karla-Bold.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf, 1);
    }
}
```

Use this class as View in `XML`

```
 <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaBold // hammerapps.views is My Package name
                android:id="@+id/txtVIEW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="VIEW"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library if you want your entire application in a specific font
[Check here](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Custom Textview

public class TextView extends android.widget.TextView {
Context mContext;
String str;
boolean isCorner;
//fonts
public static Typeface Font_name;

public TextView(Context context)  {
    super(context);
    mContext=context;
    initialiseFont(null);
}





public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)  {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext=context;
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextView, 0, 0);
    try {
        str = ta.getString(R.styleable.TextView_font_family);
        isCorner=ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextView_isCorner,false);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }
    initialiseFont(str);
}


private void initialiseFont(String font)  {

    if(font==null || font.equals("")){

    }
    else {

            Font_name = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "DroidSansFallbackanmol256.ttf");
            setTypeface(Font_name);

}
```

}

Use attrs.xml

```
 <declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="font_family" format="string"/>
    <attr name="isCorner" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```